# woo-commerce check cart items does not change language until a product is added of that language

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart, multilingual

There are two languages (Arabic & English) in my Multilingual  woo-commerce site. When I switch language from Arabic to English, check cart items does not change their language until I add an item in English language. After adding item check cart items change their language to English.

It is the same when I change language from English [image]to Arabic.

Comment: can you include the site link?